# The product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, terminology

Express as the product of disjoint cycles:

$(1\ \ 2)(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)(1\ \ 2)$

It's easy to verify that above product is equal to $(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)$.
Could we count the cycle $(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)$ as the disjoint? However, it sounds quite pointless.

Comment: Why does rewriting $(1\ 2)(1\ 2\ 3)(1\ 2)$ as $(1\ 3\ 2)$ seem "quite pointless" to you? It seems like a definite improvement to me.

Comment: Anyway, the disjoint cycle representation of a permutation is **unique** (except for the order of the factors). If you don't like the one you came up with, deal with it; you're not going to find one you like better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not pointless *at all*. It's like saying that every natural number greater than $1$ can be expressed as a product of primes. What do you get if the number is $5$. You get $5$, that's all.

And here, when we talk about product of disjoint cycles, if you have a single cycle then the cycles are trivially disjoint (since there's only one of them).

Comment: Thanks, dear Jose for clear answer! +1

Comment: @RFZ You're welcome. I hope that the way that I edited your question doesn't bother you.

Comment: Of course not! Instead i have learnt how to write permutations correctly in this forum :)

Comment: @RFZ If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I was trying to mark it but there is time limit between upvote and accepting answer as the best :) Done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the definition of disjoint is that it uses each number at most once.

Also, it is far from pointless: expressing a permutation in terms of disjoint cycles is essentially unique (up to reordering) whereas there are many ways of writing it as any product of cycles. This means we can define the cycle type of a permutation (e.g. the type of $(123)$ is $\{3\}$ and the type of $(12)(34)$ is $\{2,2\}$) and things which follow from there. For example, two elements of $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.